# Finding my IP address on windows for SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, ip, simplehttpserver

I've started an HTTP Server on my laptop using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

I want to access this from another computer in a different network. I tried finding the IP of the laptop running HTTP server using whatismyip and then called from the PC on other network like:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000
```

Because since 8000 is the default port on which it started. However, this doesn't seem to work. What is the right way?

Comment: What is `whatismyip`?

Comment: I used this website to find my public IP. Searching this on google shows the IP.

Comment: You need to forward your network IP on the router. For example if you are `192.168.1.22` within the network,  and your "whatsmyip?" address is 55.55.55.55  then you can reroute access from a port X to `192.168.1.22:8000`.  Anyone accessing `55.55.55.55:X` (your network) will end up at your webserver.

Comment: The one i'm running HTTP server on is windows. And I'm trying to access it from Ubuntu on another network.

Comment: If the computers are in separate networks, they are probably behind some kind of firewall (e.g. in your router). The keyword you're looking for is "port forwarding". But be careful! If you configure port forwarding, your service will be visible for the entire internet and might quickly be targeted by attackers (bot nets, etc.). Additionally, SimpleHTTPServer might not be the safest option to have "out in the wild".

Comment: Can you elaborate `another` network. It is too vague since network topologies are complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First you need to know your public IP address.**

This is how people find your network from outside. You can find this by Googling "whatsmyip".

For example your public ip address is `66.66.66.66`

[image]

Then you need to know your private IP address, this is how people (or machines) find your PC from within your network.

Open a cmd and type in `ipconfig`

For example your private IP address is `192.168.1.13`

[image: This is mine]

**Now comes the hard part**

You need to port forward people accessing the public ip to your private ip within the network.

It looks something like this:

[image]

[Here is a comprehensive guide on how to do that](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/)

Most likely you need to go to your gateway ip, mine is `192.168.1.1` if you see the above picture.

Login to the router and find a port forwarding section.

There you forward incoming requests to `HTTP/TCP PORT 8000` to your private ip address port 8000, for example: 192.168.1.13:8000

It would look something like this:

[image]